# Iterating the days of the week

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code which iterates a chosen set of days and should ring `true` if today is part of the chosen set. However, `isDay` rings `false` regardless of the `daysChosen` or what `today` happens to be. So what am I missing here?..

```
var date = new Date;
var isDay;
var today=date.toString().substring(0,4)
//console.log(today)//good
for (var daysChosen of ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'])
{
  console.log(daysChosen)//good
   isDay = today==daysChosen ? true : false
}
console.log(isDay)//bad, should be true if today is part of daysChosen
```

***Update:*** 
Ok, this is some BULL ****!!!... how on earth can this evaluate to true given that `today` is in the array!?...

```
for (var value of ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri'])
    {      
      var _day =  (today!=value) ? true : false 
      break;
    }
console.log(_day)
```

Comment: you will need to `break;` your loop after `isDay = today==daysChosen ? true : false` if it is true or else it will only be true for 'Thu'

Comment: lol "ring `true`" "rings `false`" Inventive! I like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few major problems that are causing you issues in your code.

1. `var today=date.toString().substring(0,4)` - The days are 3 characters long, so your getting the extra space at the end. `today === "Sun "`, notice the extra space.
2. Your not breaking out of your loops once you find the correct value as other answers have pointed out.

---

You can simply use the `indexOf` method. It returns the index of the given string or -1 if its not contained in the array.

```
var date = new Date();
// first 3 characters from string for day of week
var today = date.toString().substring(0,3);
var days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'];

var isInDays = days.indexOf(today) > 0; // indexOf returns -1 if not contained
```

Or to fix your existing code:

```
var date = new Date;
var isDay;
var today=date.toString().substring(0,3)
//console.log(today)//good
for (var daysChosen of ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'])
{
    console.log(daysChosen)//good
    isDay = today==daysChosen ? true : false
    if(isDay) break; // must break once you find it or you will keep overriding the value.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop continue looping when `isDay` becomes `true` and in the next iterations could assign `false` to it. You could use `break` statement to exit loop:

```
var isDay = false;
for (var daysChosen of ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'])
{
    if (today == daysChosen) {
        isDay = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

You can also use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function to check if array contains `today`. (`!!` is double negation):

```
var isDay = !!['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu'].find(function(day) {
    return day === today;           
})
```

Unfortunately `find` is not [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) with all browsers.

Comment: Any other solution? none of the ones above are working : https://jsfiddle.net/znibble/7e06LmLe/

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array of things and want to check if it has something, I would use the new [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) property on arrays:

```
["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu"].includes(today);
```

Also, instead of extracting the day of the week from the string output, use [`Date.prototype.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

---

If you don't want to include the polyfill, you can use this trick I learned from [Codegolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com):

```
~["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu"].indexOf(today);
```

The `~` is a binary NOT operator, which will transform the bits in a data type to their opposite. The binary NOT of -1, which is returned from `.indexOf()` when there are no instances of the search term, is 0.  In JavaScript there's a concept called coercion, which means that when there's typal dissonance, like adding booleans, for example, there are values of one type that will convert to another. For example, all numbers that are not zero are coerced to `true`, and `0` coerces to `false`. Becuase of this, if you put the above text into an `if` statement, it will act as if it is an `.includes()`.

---

**A better way**

You're extracting the day of the week from the `Date.toString()`, which is not good practice. Consider using array access and `Date.prototype.getDay()` to make the process a lot more logical:

```
let today = new Date().getDay();
//   Sun., Mon., Tue., etc.
if ([true, true, true, true, true, false, false][today]) {
  // Day is matched

} else {
  // Day is not matched
}
```

This has some advantages

1. Ultimate Customizability. You can specify exactly which days you want to match
2. Doesn't rely on strings. Your method of extracting from the string is going to get tripped up in non-English user agents, becuase their Date Strings will be different.

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm guessing Internet Explorer or Edge becuas those are the major browsers that don't support it. [On the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) there is a polyfill which you can use so `.includes()` will work everywhere

Comment: Keep in mind that these will not assign the variable, they will only evaluate to true if `today` is included in the array

Comment: `today` is in the array and all examples should return `true', but they're not. What gives?

Comment: Check to make the exact string you want is from the array.